# How to calculate the derivative of the pseudo-inverse matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, pseudoinverse

I have the following equation:

$$
\begin{equation} 
 x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb
\end{equation}
$$

and I need to calculate the derivative of k-th entry of x with respect to A:

$$
\begin{equation} 
\frac{\partial x(k)}{\partial A}
\end{equation}
$$

I really don't know how to solve it! Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward calculation shows that
\begin{align}
dx(k)
&= d\left(e_k(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb\right)\\
&= e_k^T d(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb + e_k^T (A^TA)^{-1} dA^Tb\\
&= -e_k^T (A^TA)^{-1} d(A^TA) (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb + e_k^T (A^TA)^{-1} dA^Tb\\
&= -e_k^T (A^TA)^{-1} (dA^T A + A^TdA) (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb + e_k^T (A^TA)^{-1} dA^Tb\\
\end{align}
Therefore, the $(i,j)$-th entry of $\frac{\partial x(k)}{\partial A}$ is given by
$$
-e_k^T (A^TA)^{-1} (E_{ji} A + A^TE_{ij}) (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb + e_k^T (A^TA)^{-1} E_{ji}b.
$$